# too many curly brace using verbdef

Tags: verbatim, braces

I would like to create an inline verbatim text for a regular expression. The verbdef package does not like when I put curly braces into its second argument. I tried with escaping backslashes but that did not work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbdef}
\verbdef{\re2}{([^/]*/){3}}

\begin{document}

What is the meaning of the \re2 regular expression?

\end{document}
```

I got the following error message:

> (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ltxmisc/verbdef.sty)
>
> ! Too many }'s.
>
> l.4 \verbdef{\re2}{([^/]*/){3}}

I looked for a long name of curly brace like `\curlybraceleft` but did not find one.

How can I solve this typesetting problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thanks, both the welcoming and the typesetting tip. And the edit.

Comment: You are welcome, please edit the question adding where the `\begin{document}` should be placed, I am not familiar with the `verbdef` package and whether `\verbdef` must only be called in the preamble? :)

Comment: zeroth, I made a minimal example that showed the error message and the problem. When you want to use that inline verbatim text, you simply use the `\re` macro that was being defined in the preamble.

Comment: No, I meant that your MWE is missing a `\begin{document}` in the example. I do not know where to place it (albeit I now do) :)

Comment: zeroth, I added a `\begin{document}` and a usage example of the defined macro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of `verbdef` is indeed rather scanty. Your attempt has two issues.

First of all you can't define a command that has digit and letters in its name: either the name is a single digit or letters only.

Second issue: if the text to be stored verbatim has braces in it, you have to use a syntax like the ordinary `\verb` command, so for instance

```
\verbdef{\re}|([^/]*/){3}|
```

where the delimiter character (here `|`) does not appear in the verbatim text.